# Intall Brother MFC-J435w Printer

Tags: printing, ubuntu-drivers

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Desktop PC.  I'm trying to get my `Brother MFC-J435w Printer`. The Software Center did not have drivers for the printer so I tried installing the Generic driver that was available and "recommended."  I tried sending several PDF docs to the printer but could not get the printer to run.  Since I'm new to Ubuntu am I missing something?  Are there drivers available that I'm just not finding. Have been working this issue for several hours with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to head to this Brother page, 
http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj430w_all,

Then chosse Linux(deb) and download the printer driver.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Found the files and downloaded the Driver Install Tool, LPR printer driver (deb package) and CUPSwrapper printer driver (deb package).  Now to figure out how to finish the install.

Comment: Hmmm...thought I responded to this a couple of days ago.  Any I download linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.  Tried to download the lpr and cups files.  The system indicated is was placing them in the Software Center.  However, when I check the Software Center the download files are not there.  The was a message in the download process that there was no companion file...or something like that.  Should all three of the downloads go the the same location?  Should the downloads be directed to the Download File, The Software Center Any Hints?

Comment: By default downloaded files are in ~/Download (/home/user/download), you can install it by typing in terminal $ sudo dpkg -i filename.deb, change filename with downloaded file or use *.deb to install all downloaded deb file.